# How to use list objects as arguments inside a python function?

Tags: python, list, function, keyword-argument, etherscan

I am new to programming and I am stuck with this following problem.

I can't find a way to pass my list objects as arguments within the following function.

My goal with the function is to run through all the list objects one by one and save the data as a variable named erc20.

[Link to .json file](https://pastebin.com/Vf9A44F4) // [Link to etherscan-python github](https://github.com/pcko1/etherscan-python)

```
from etherscan import Etherscan
import json


with open('adress-tracker.json') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)

    print(json_data)


# Here we create a result list, in which we will store our addresses
result_list = [json_dict['Address'] for json_dict in json_data]

eth = Etherscan("APIKEY") #removed my api key

erc20 = eth.get_erc20_token_transfer_events_by_address(address = result_list, startblock="0", endblock="999999999", sort='asc')

print(erc20)
```

This will return the following Error:

```
AssertionError: Error! Invalid address format -- NOTOK
```

When I directly add the address or link it to a variable it works just fine. However I need to find a way how to apply the functions to all addresses, as I plan to add in hundreds.

I tried changing the list to a directory and also tried to implement Keyword Arguments with (*result_list) or created a new variable called params with all needed arguments. Then used (*params). But unfortunately I can't wrap my head around how to solve this problem.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Are you aware of `func(*args)` and `func(**kwargs)` notations?

Comment: `address` parameter should be a string not list, so use a for loop to iterate through the `results_list` and pass the value one at a time to the address parameter

Comment: this function can't get list of addresses and you have to use `for`-loop to check every address separatelly.

Answer (score 0):

This function expects single address so you have to use `for`-loop to check every address separatelly

```
erc20 = []

for address in result_list:
    result = eth.get_erc20_token_transfer_events_by_address(address=address, 
                                                            startblock="0", 
                                                            endblock="999999999", 
                                                            sort='asc')
    erc20.append(result)
    
print(erc20)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working code which works for me:

```
import os
import json
from etherscan import Etherscan

TOKEN = os.getenv('ETHERSCAN_TOKEN')
eth = Etherscan(TOKEN)

with open('addresses.json') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
    #print(json_data)

erc20 = []

for item in json_data:
    print(item['Name'])
    result = eth.get_erc20_token_transfer_events_by_address(address=item['Address'],
                                                            startblock="0",
                                                            endblock="999999999",
                                                            sort='asc')
    erc20.append(result)
    print('len(result):', len(result))
    
#print(erc20)

#for item in erc20:
#    print(item)
```

Result:

```
Name 1
len(result): 44
Name 2
len(result): 1043
Name 3
len(result): 1
```